# active class with bootstrap sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

The sidebar needs to change active class after click.This is my bootstrap code and i tried it with this javascript code but it doesn't works.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.sidebar1 a').filter(function(){return this.href==location.href}).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    $('.sidebar1 a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active') 
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="list-group">
         <ul class="siderbar1">
              <li><a href="HhwController" class="list-group-item active">Hoe het werkt</a></li>
              <li><a href="OveronsController" class="list-group-item">Over ons</a></li>
             <li><a href="VpController" class="list-group-item">Veiligheid en privacy</a></li>
             <li><a href="FAQController" class="list-group-item">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="Contactform" class="list-group-item">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: yes it will not work because page is getting refreshed while you click on the link so let me know if are you getting the controller name on the page using some variable or not?

Comment: The link is a controller name in codeigniter and it refreshes to a new page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC with Bootstrap Navbar - Set Selected Item to Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407367/mvc-with-bootstrap-navbar-set-selected-item-to-active)

Comment: It seems that the HTML class is "siderbar1" rather than "sidebar1".

Answer (score 0):

please try like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // $('.sidebar1 a').filter(function(){return this.href==location.href}).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); i have not tried this line
    $('.sidebar1 a').click(function(){
      $(".list-group-item").removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');          
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: the active class didn't change when I click on a link when I tried you're code

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way how to unset .active class form siblings and set it to current one is

```
$('.sidebar1 a').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar1 .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.sidebar1 a').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar1 .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove `active` class from all `anchor` tags. Then, you can add `active` class to the `anchor` tag which is clicked. Also, you have to use `e.preventDefault()`, to stop browser from redirecting.

```js
    $('.siderbar1 a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.siderbar1 a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="list-group">
         <ul class="siderbar1">
              <li><a href="HhwController" class="list-group-item active">Hoe het werkt</a></li>
              <li><a href="OveronsController" class="list-group-item">Over ons</a></li>
             <li><a href="VpController" class="list-group-item">Veiligheid en privacy</a></li>
             <li><a href="FAQController" class="list-group-item">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="Contactform" class="list-group-item">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sir, i used your code but the links are not working anymore for some reason. it changes the active class but it stays on the same page. @vipin kumar

Comment: If you want link to work, then you can remove `e.preventDefault();`. But then, each time your page refresh it will reset your active state. Then you have to use MVC  manage the active state.

Comment: So do I need to change something in my MVC or in my javascript to make it work?

Comment: you need do something in MVC. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407367/mvc-with-bootstrap-navbar-set-selected-item-to-active