# HtmlHelpers in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to port this code over to mvc 6, any help is appreciated, the code compiles but the method is not available in my views on `@Html.IsActive`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace Blah.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {

        public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controller, string action)
        {
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

            var routeAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
            var routeController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

            var returnActive = (controller == routeController && action == routeAction);

            return returnActive ? "active" : "";
        }

    }
}
```

In the View I have the namespace referenced:

```
@using Blah.Web.Helpers;
```

Comment: have you added `@using Blah.Web.Helpers` in your view?

Comment: yes I have.  Sorry for not posting that info.

Comment: HtmlHelper should be IHtmlHelper

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the method signature, `HtmlHelper` should be `IHtmlHelper`

See Example below

```
namespace Blah.Web.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static string IsActive(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controller, string action)
        {
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

            var routeAction = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
            var routeController = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

            return (controller == routeController && action == routeAction) ? "active" : "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing this answer so the first line reads something like 'In the method signaure, `HtmlHelper` should be `IHtmlHelper`.  This would help other users in comparing the code Q + A code snippets.

Comment: Is this a new requirement in MVC 6? In my MVC 4 app I do NOT use the interface version and everything works fine.

Comment: Yes, only aply to .net core