# How to append active class to existing class on clicked menu items?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have `menu items on master page` and if users click on that menu item I want show it active. I want to append Active to existing class to make it active.

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
 <div class="menu-items-navigation">
  <div class="Classy-item" class="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index", controllers: "Classy")">
      <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Classy")"   >
          <div style="padding-top: 50px;">Classy Items</div>
       </a>
   </div>
   <div class="Regular-stuff">
      <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "RegularStuff")">
           <div style="padding-top: 50px;">Regular Stuff</div>
      </a>
   </div>

   <div class="Popular-Vessels">
       <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PopularVessels")">
           <div style="padding-top: 50px;">Popular Vessels</div>
       </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now if I want this menu item to be `Active` I have 1 class called as Active in which I want to give to this div if user click any of this 3 menu items.

For example, if I want to make `Regular Stuff as Active when user clicks` on it then it will be like this:

```
<div class="Regular-stuff Active">
```

If user click on Classy Item then :

```
<div class="Classy-item Active">
```

Code taken from here [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc):

```
 public static string IsSelected(this HtmlHelper html, string controllers = "", string actions = "", string cssClass = "Active")
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = html.ViewContext;
            bool isChildAction = viewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.IsChildAction;

            if (isChildAction)
                viewContext = html.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext;

            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = viewContext.RouteData.Values;
            string currentAction = routeValues["action"].ToString();
            string currentController = routeValues["controller"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actions))
                actions = currentAction;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllers))
                controllers = currentController;

            string[] acceptedActions = actions.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();
            string[] acceptedControllers = controllers.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();

            return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
                cssClass : String.Empty;
        }
```

But I am confused here that how to class this Isselected method when particular menu items will be clicked as I can't use class attributes 2 times on div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you can't declare the `class` attribute twice, but you can combine them like this:

```
<div class="Classy-item @Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index", controllers: "Classy")">
```

Which will render if not selected:

```
<div class="Classy-item ">
```

Or render this if selected:

```
<div class="Classy-item Active">
```