# Navigation bar as a partial view. What about "active" class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, partial

I've got a navigation bar as a partial view - it contains page links. Everything works fine, but how do I use the `<li class="active">` now? Since there is no controller, I can't use the `active` class to highlight on which page user is currently on. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `class="active"`? And what do you mean there is no controller?

Comment: Did you try javascript?

Comment: Umm... It's just css class to highlight the link of the page that user is currently on. There is obviously no controller that returns the partial, because.... it's a partial. Didn't tried js. More details please?

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9UB/).

Comment: Oh it's pretty nice, but there is one issue. If user is on another page, and refreshes it, the partial is also getting refreshed - so the tag dissapears and user won't know which is the current site, since js removed the color tag after refresh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "active" class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect on which page you should set the active class you can check the ViewContext.RouteData. Ex:

```
<li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Action1" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Action1", "Action1", "Home")</li>
 ..................
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am faced same Issue Use the Following Code Given Below

```html
<a class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "HomePage" ? "active" : "") " href=@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName" > </a>
// If the link in the Action and 
// HomePage is My current Active Page
// Active is Class
```