# How to use ViewContext?

Tags: css, asp.net, viewcontext

I have layout page in asp.net MVC application and this page contains a navbar

```
 <ul class="sidenavbar">
   <li><a   style="font-size:large">ASP.NET Tutorial</a></li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Home")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Introduction", "Introduction")</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Getting Started", "GettingStarted")</li>
 </ul>
```

See I have **actionmethod** for each item in my **navbar** now I want to apply **css** class **active** to currently selected **list** **item** how can I achieve this using **ViewContext** or if there is any better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "active" class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Home" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
  <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "About" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
  <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Contact" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can i access ViewContext.RouteData in a c# class actually i want to make an extention method similar to ActionLink() that does this job in addition?