# What is @Html.IsSelected(controller: "Dashboards")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am vb.net familiar. Have a razor c# piece of code. Went through pages of documentation but I cannot find out what does this code do?

```
<li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Dashboards")>
```

I understand that runs function `IsSelected` of Html class but what is the meaning of argument passed to it?

Comment: I think the answer in this post describes it <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to under stand what this does

```
 @Html.IsSelected(controller: "Dashboards")
```

@ tells razor to output the following to the html code by executing

```
Html.IsSelected
```

the parameter is a Named or optional parameter. It is basically saying sets the value of parameter with name "`controller`" to `"Dashboards"`

The function's definition might be like

```
IsSelected(int notUsed = 0, string notUsed2 = null, string controller = "dead beef")
```

so that you can save yourself some typing instead calling `IsSelected(0, null, "Dashboards")`