# Bootstrap nav random highlighting (active?) when moving from .html to .aspx

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap template that came in an index.html file.  I need to add some c# code, so I moved it over to an Default.aspx page.

Everything works, but the page loads with a seemingly random nav item highlighted(Is this active).  The page loads with the Contact nav item highlighted.  I tried setting the active class to the Home item.

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll active">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#page-top">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#portfolio">Demo's</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#screens">Screen Shots</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#new">New Things</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="files/Resume.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting is not random, but rather coming from the `.active` class. If your above example, `Home` will be highlighted. Whichever nav element has the 'active' class will be the one that is highlighted. I've created an example showcasing this by changing `Screen shots` to active [**here**](http://www.bootply.com/EoDDALLMyx).

If you want the `Contact` page to be highlighted, you need to set that tab as active:

```
<li class="page-scroll active">
  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

For changing between multiple pages, you'll want to **output** this `active` class manually through your back-end code. There's already a great answer on how to do that in C# [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20411015/2341603).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: With my code and your code, the Contact is still the active nav when the page loads.  When I try setting active in an html file, nothing happens, but at least the Contact is not active.  I would prefer Nothing active when the page loads, although having Home active is far preferable to having Contact active.  This is a single page app.