# How to toggle class active in asp.net razor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When, home menu is active (selected), render this

```
<li class="active"><a href = "~/Home" >Home</a></li>
```

Otherwise, when home menu is inactive (not selected), render this

```
<li><a href = "~/Home" >Home</a></li>
```

Comment: There a multiple ways - using a `HtmlHelper` extension method that returns a class name based on the current route, or assignung a value to `ViewBag` and using some javascript to set it, etc etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "home menu is active"..? Do you refer to an action inside your controller?

Comment: The extension method in dom's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) is one example

Answer (score 0):

Try this type it May Help You.

```
<li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Home" ? "active" : "")"><a href = "~/Home" >Home</a></li>
```