# How can I filter my partial views with a radio button in asp.net-core w/o javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, forms, radio-button, asp.net-core-2.0

I want my users to be able to sort the content of the page thus displaying a partial view depending on what they click. This would be a clear case to use radio buttons as only one can be selected at a time.

However I'm not sure how to call an action method on just a radio button.

This is my current implementation **without radiobuttons**

```
<a asp-action="Bookings" asp-controller="User" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-sortOrder="All">Alle lektioner</a>
<a asp-action="Bookings" asp-controller="User" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-sortOrder="Upcoming">Kommende lektioner</a>
<a asp-action="Bookings" asp-controller="User" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-sortOrder="History">Historik</a>
```

Using bootstrap radio buttons this is my template but I'm not able to make these hit an actionmethod in my controller. I've thought about creating *onclick* on the input but I'm not sure that possible and additionally I don't know how to asp-route-sortOrder in an onclick

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-primary active">
     <input type="radio"id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> All
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Upcoming
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> History
  </label> 
</div>
```

I prefer to not use javascript if possible.

Comment: Add a submit button along with the radio buttons and wrap all those inside a a form tag. Inside the action method which handles the form submit, get the filtered subset of data based on the radio button selection(which is part of the submitted form data),and return that to the corresponding view where it will be rendered

Comment: To add to @Shyju comment, you would need to give the radio buttons a `name` attribute the value can be submitted to the controller (preferably by binding to a model property)

Comment: But what is the concern with your current implementation using links?

Comment: Going to try that out thanks. I just thought to myself it programatically makes more sense to use radio buttons.

Comment: Also I want the selected button to appear as marked, but since the buttons are in the main view, I suppose the first will be set to marked on every reload anyways? Hmm

Comment: If you using radio buttons that are bound to a property (using `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` then if the value of the property matches one of the button values, then it will be selected (otherwise none will be). But you can also highlight your links based on the current route to indicate what is being currently filtered

Comment: I see, thanks. Currently I'm routing the sortorder so If I was to highlight my links based on a viewdata value is there a smart way to do this without writing a clumsy if/else condition for all 3 buttons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162712/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-j-kirk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to just highlight the link indicating the current route (sortOrder) by conditionally adding a class name. Refer [How to add “active” class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) for some examples of how to do that, but to answer your question, start with a view model to represent what you want in the view

```
public class BookingsVM
{
    public string SortOrder { get; set; } // to bind to the radio buttons
    public IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings { get; set; } // the collection of records to display in the view
}
```

Then the controller method would be

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Bookings(string sortOrder)
{
    var bookings = .... // your code to get Bookings based on the value of sortOrder
    BookingsVM model = new BookingsVM
    {
        SortOrder = sortOrder,
        Bookings = bookings
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And the view

```
@model BookingsVM
....
@using(Html.BeginForm("Bookings", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SortOrder, "All", new { id = "" })
        <span>Alle lektioner</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SortOrder, "Upcoming", new { id = "" })
        <span>Kommende lektioner</span>
    </label>
    // .... ditto for History
    <input type="submit value="Sort" />
}
@foreach(var booking in Model.Bookings)
{
    // .... display results here
}
```

Note that because the browser has no knowledge of your route definitions, submitting the form will result in a url that is `../User/Bookings?sortOrder=All` (i.e using a query string value). If you want `../User/Bookings/All`, then you will need to use some javascipt to make the redirect.

As a side note, the fact the your possible values are "All", "Upcoming" and "History" suggests that you actually filtering the results (i.e. using a `.Where()` clause) rather that sorting the results (using an `.OrderBy()`) so a more appropriate property name might be `Filter` rather than `SortOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to solve your problem

1. convert your partial views to [`View Components`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) then load them
   by JavaScript
2. make that view act like a layout ***(NESTED LAYOUT)*** then load the
   different sections as views according to selected option

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout
   - [Nested Layout Pages with Razor](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/164/nested-layout-pages-with-razor)