# razor compilation error using isSelected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

in razor view 5 using mvc 5.2

```
@Html.IsSelected
```

is not recognized and produces a compilation Error while in another project in runtime it is used and works just fin any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: What is your `IsSelected` extension method? That is not part of mvc

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "IsSelected" is part of the default Razor syntax and not an extension method in one of your other projects.

You can do a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to do a global search on the project that "IsSelected" works in and look for "IsSelected(this HtmlHelper html". If you find this in a file somewhere, you have identified "IsSelected" as an extension that you/someone has created in the past.

Here is an another StackOverflow question that has the "IsSelected" extension method as an answer that you can reference in case you can't find it in your old project.

[How to add "active" class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)