# Menu item active not activating for theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement this theme for my website https://getstisla.com/demo/dashboard-ecommerce.html

I noticed that on the site, if you click a menu item, it sets a list item active on the menu.

However, I have tried to implement it and it but when I click on the menu item, nothing is set as active aside from the home item.

This is the menu

```
<div class="main-sidebar sidebar-style-2">
<aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-brand">
        @Html.ActionLink("App", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "" })
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-brand sidebar-brand-sm">
        @Html.ActionLink("A", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "" })
    </div>
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="active"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link"><i class="far fa-square"></i><span>Home Page</span></a></li>

        <li class="menu-header">AM Mode</li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-fire"></i><span>Configuration</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a asp-area="Configuration" asp-controller="AC" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">A C</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="Configuration" asp-controller="B" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
</div>
```

I have tried searching through the files for the javascript that sets the menu item active but I haven't found it so far. I was hoping someone could take a look and see if I'm missing something.

The files can be downloaded from here https://cssauthor.com/bootstrap-templates/#Admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a ASP.NET question IMO. Possible duplication of [How to add “active” class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc)

**EDIT:**

The theme is hardcoding those `class="active"` in static `*.html` files, this theme is not a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

> I have tried searching through the files for the javascript that sets the menu item active

You won't find it, JavaScript is not setting the active class.

[image]

Comment: Not really. its more css jquery as the question I asked was if this particular theme had that chunk of code instead of how to add an active class to a html actionlink. I already know that.

Comment: Oh... Thank you. I'll need to create one by myself then.