# How i can underline the current page inside my bootstrap <nav>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap code which define our main menu navigation :-

```
<div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9">
                                <div class="main-menu  d-none d-lg-block">
                                    <nav>
                                        <ul id="navigation">
                                            <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/home/FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/home/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

but i need to make the current page underline using bootstrap if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put a class in the one that is active and in css give the underline to the class
Like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">home</a></li>
```

css:

```
.active{
    border-bottom: xxxx;
    border-color:xxxx;
    border-style:xxx;
    }
```

Comment: But how i can know the active one?

Comment: Are you using php?

Comment: okay so i think this link explains it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You need some JavaScript for this. Basically, you need to add a class dynamically, e.g. `active` to your active `<li>` element and then add some styles to this class. Check [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp) for further details.