# ASP.Net Core Web App - How can i prevent Navbar style from reloading when navigating to other pages?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am having a problem with the style refreshing on my navbar I click on a link to go to a new page. Is there any way i can fix this? I am new to using ASP.NET core webapp.

Here is a video of the issue I am having:
[Video](https://www.veed.io/view/95ee791a-f6f2-422e-9cd0-027610d7eda1?panel=share)

Here is my Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<body >
    <header>
        
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light gradient-custom border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Watch It Later</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Privacy", "Privacy", "Home",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
                            
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Watch List", "Index", "Movies",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Find Movies", "ShowSearchForm", "Movies",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="page-stack">
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                &copy; 2023 - WishlistWebApp - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Is there a way to prevent the navbar from reloading?

Comment: Sounds like this may be an [X/Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question. Are you just trying to maintain the style of the selected item as you navigate? Sorry, I'm not watching the video.

Comment: If I understand what you are attempting to do then this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410623/how-to-add-active-class-to-html-actionlink-in-asp-net-mvc) has your solution. In the selected answer look under where it says 'Late Edit' and where it says 'Works with .NET Core'. Basically, you want to create an HtmlHelper Extension method and use it on the `li` element, then each time the page loads it will use the HtmlHelper method to determine the route values, and based on these values it will append an 'active' style to the nav element for the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to retain a 'selected' style on your nav item across page navigations. If I am correct then you don't want to take your approach where you 'prevent nav style from reloading on navigation'.

The way to do this is with a custom HtmlHelper method. You create the helper method and then append it to the `li` elements class. When the page loads it determines the route values and sets the style based on the current route values.

---

Create a Html Helper Extension method. This method will be called each page load and will use the route values to determine the current page, then based on these values it will apply the 'selected' css style to the 'li' element where the 'action' and 'controller' parameters match the current route.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string IsSelected(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controllers, string actions, string cssClass = "selected")
    {
        string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;
        string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string;

        IEnumerable<string> acceptedActions = (actions ?? currentAction).Split(',');
        IEnumerable<string> acceptedControllers = (controllers ?? currentController).Split(',');

        return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
                cssClass : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then use it your navigation on the `li` element, like so...

```
<li class="nav-item @Html.IsSelected(actions:"Index", controllers: "Home")">
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
</li>
<li class="nav-item @Html.IsSelected(actions:"Privacy", controllers: "Home")">
    @Html.ActionLink("Privacy", "Privacy", "Home",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
</li>
<li class="nav-item @Html.IsSelected(actions:"Index", controllers: "Movies")">
    @Html.ActionLink("Watch List", "Index", "Movies",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
</li>
<li class="nav-item @Html.IsSelected(actions:"ShowSearchForm", controllers: "Movies")">
    @Html.ActionLink("Find Movies", "ShowSearchForm", "Movies",null, new {@class = "navlink-custom"})
</li>
```

... and don't forget to add a css style...

```
.selected {
    background-color: #d0eef9;
    border-radius: .4em;
}
```

Comment: Hey Quaabaam, I implemented this and it is displaying the selected page. This is nice but what I am trying to fix is when i click a link on the navbar, while the page is loading the images, The navbar links revert back to an unstyled <a> (being blue and underlined) for a second until the images finish loading on the page. I am trying to make it so the links on the navbar styles do not revert to default styling while the page is loading. But the answer you gave me did fix an issue i was looking to resolve once i resolve the styling override while the page loads.

Comment: I also just tested this in Microsoft Edge and it seems like I'm only having that flickering problem with the styling in Firefox. It waits for the page to load when using Edge.